# Making an element the same height as a dynamically defined height of an adjacent element

Tags: html, css, height

[image: Three boxes]

I have three boxes on my website - demonstrated in the image above. two of them are dynamically sized i.e. they just fit the text that's inside them. The problem is the third box, marked in green in the picture, which I want to just neatly fill up the remaining space, i.e. the height of the left box - the height of the right box (and minus the margin). How do I do this? I.e. I don't have a problem with the setup itself of the three boxes, but I can't figure out how to stretch the green box to the desired height without pre-determining the height of every box.

Many thanks

Edit: so I figured out how to do it if you only have 2 boxes (i.e. one on the left and one the right). just give the one on the right "position: absolute" and "bottom:0px" and "top:0px" and it stretches out the full distance. Can't figure out if/how this solution is applicable to my case though...

Edit: so I came up with a hack to do it using the method mentioned in the edit above. I make one container div for all the boxes with "overflow: auto". I do the larger box on the left, then create the green box on the right side with the attributes "position:absolute;right:15px;top:0px;bottom:0px;" making it stretch from the top to the bottom, the same height as the box on the left. I then add the 2nd text box  with a "float:left;". I add a third box which will contain the text of the green box - with a 15 px thick border on its top in the same color as the background (15px is the size of my margin btw). Tadah!

...but, if there's an easier/cleaner way of doing it, please do reply!

Comment: Could you please put your code so far into a jsFiddle.

Comment: do any of the boxes have a min/max-height?

Comment: @Danield I'm not sure. [This is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/PFQWg/).

Comment: I realized my hack didn't work unless there was a min-height to the box in the upper right, so yes, that box has a min-height now.

Comment: Sorry, strike that, it works fine without min-height, might have been a bug in chromebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: As pointed out by @Marcus, `height:100%;` does not work without setting a height to the parent. Because of this I wrote a bit of JS to do the job better. It gets the height of the left hand pannel and then subtracts the height of the top pannel and margin before setting the height.** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/PFQWg/)

[image]

```
.bottomRight{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}
.topRight{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var mainHeight = $("#leftMain").height();
    var topHeight = $("#topRight").height();
    var newHeight = mainHeight - topHeight - 15;
    $("#bottomRight").css("height", newHeight);
});
```

Comment: height: 100% doesn't work unless the parent div has a set height.

Comment: @Marcus You are correct, my mistake. Give me a sec to edit it.

Comment: Thanks! I would prefer a solution without javascript (though this is great)

Comment: I'm not sure if a non-javascript option is available appart from the hack you used.